# Is there a way to program a command to lookup and show contents of a row in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, discord, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I want to program a simple command in a Discord bot that just outputs the contents of a row. I am using Discord.Js and I was thinking of perhaps using a website that converts a Google Sheet to a REST API, which might make it easier for me. (Example: https://sheety.co/) I have an example bellow of a basic idea of what I want to accomplish.

How would I accomplish this? (I am an amateur programmer and I would really appreciate some help and guidance)

**Example:**

- Using this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aNxCQhpagiO9hTWH_joeQncG3mDCh8I21puf9r0EQcY/edit?usp=sharing
- Assuming the prefix for the bot is an exclamation mark (!)

When the Discord bot gets issued a command "!points Adam", it should return with something like this:
Adam's Points: 18.4
Suggested: 7
Recorded: 3
Edited: 7
Above Minimum: Yes
[Example Chat Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47h1p.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Discord Bot to read and update spreadsheet in JavaScript via Google Sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915821/get-discord-bot-to-read-and-update-spreadsheet-in-javascript-via-google-sheets-a)

Comment: @CodeCamper Yes but no. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

You can opt for anyone of these solutions:

#### Google Sheets API

Sheets API allows you to connect your app (Discord Bot, in this case) to Google Sheets. You can view a spreadsheet, add or view data, delete data, and do a lot more operations. You can use it to connect your bot to the sheet and get required data from the spreadsheet directly. You can make handsome amount of free calls.

READ: [Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) and [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)

#### Google Apps Script

Google Apps Script (GAS) is JS-like platform for developing on Google Apps, like Google Sheets. You can create a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions) to return rows from the sheet. Then, you can use `google.script.run()` in your client-side code (Discord Bot) to call that custom function. You can make handsome amount of free calls.

READ: [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

#### Third-party Solutions

Third-party solutions like Sheetsu or Sheety provides similar functionality, but they're easier to set up and use than Google Apps Scripts. They're paid services and offer lesser free calls than GAS.